# Prolog Convert a list in a list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

I need to convert a list of elements into a list of lists. 
For example, if i have the list [1,2,3,4] the output must be [[1],[2],[3],[4]], one element per list.

```
create([],_, _, _).
create([H|T], Aux, X, Result) :-
   append([H], Aux, X),
   Result = [X],
   create(T, X, _, Result).
```

I always get false... is this even possible to do?

Comment: Yes it is possible and much easier than you are making it. First, consider the base case, `convert([], []).` which says that the empty list converts to the empty list. Your base case doesn't make sense. It says the empty list converts to anything. Then do a recursive case, `convert([H|T], ...)` You fill in the rest.. what happens to `H`? What happens to `T`?

Comment: but should i use append?

Comment: You really need a good name for that relation first! Say `singletons/2`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility to define this relation is by using DCGs. They yield easily readable code when describing lists. Let's stick with the name singletons as suggested by @false in the comments:

```
singletons([]) -->        % the empty list
   [].                    % is empty
singletons([H|T]) -->     % the head of a nonempty list
   [[H]],                 % is a list on its own
   singletons(T).         % and so is the tail
```

You can query this directly with phrase/2:

```
   ?- phrase(singletons([1,2,3,4]),X).
X = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

Or write a wrapper-predicate with phrase/2 as the single goal:

```
singletons(L,Ls) :-
   phrase(singletons(L),Ls).
```

And query that:

```
   ?- singletons([1,2,3,4],Ls).
Ls = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

The predicate also works the other way around:

```
   ?- singletons(L,[[1],[2],[3],[4]]).
L = [1,2,3,4] ? ;
no
```

As well as the most general query:

```
   ?- singletons(L,Ls).
L = Ls = [] ? ;
L = [_A],
Ls = [[_A]] ? ;
L = [_A,_B],
Ls = [[_A],[_B]] ?
...
```

Alternatively you can also define a simple predicate that describes a relation between an arbitrary element and itself in brackets and then use maplist/3 from library(apply) to apply it on every element of a list:

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).

embraced(X,[X]).

singletons(L,Ls) :-
   maplist(embraced,L,Ls).
```

This version yields the same results for the above queries. However, it is more efficient. To see that consider the following query from above:

```
   ?- singletons(L,[[1],[2],[3],[4]]).
L = [1,2,3,4]
```

Above you had to enter `;` to make Prolog search for further solutions and subsequently fail (indicated by `no`). With this version there are no unnecessary choice points left and Prolog is succeeding deterministically for the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
create([],[]).

create([H|T],[[H]|T2]):- create(T,T2).
```

I tried

```
?- create([1,2,3,4],X).
```

and the result was

```
X = [[1], [2], [3], [4]].
```

Comment: What about `create(Xs,Ys)`?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: Try it out! That is `?- create(Xs,Ys).`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work that way, I wrote it to run if insert either of the parameters, what do you want it to output when u insert both as a variable?

Comment: Well, with *very low* effort, you could make that case work too!

Comment: That's interesting, I can't imagine what results will I expect, what do you have in mind?

Comment: Exchange the order of the clauses.